# Change button class and value for each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, input

I just made a timer with control, but in the control button i need some help.

Initially there have a button with START value. have to change the class and value to "STOP" for the 1st click and for the 2nd click change the class & value to "RESUME".

DEFAULT.   `<input class="start" type="button" value="START" />`

1st click. `<input class="stop" type="button" value="STOP" />`

2nd click. `<input class="resume" type="button" value="RESUME" />`

3rd click. `<input class="stop" type="button" value="STOP" />`

4th click. `<input class="resume" type="button" value="RESUME" />`

Can you help me in this? and forgive my bad English.

FYI: i am using JQUERY MOBILE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't worked in JQuery mobile but this should be the way

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("start")){
            $(this).removeClass("start");
            $(this).addClass("stop");
            $(this).val("STOP");
        }else  if($(this).hasClass("resume")){
            $(this).removeClass("resume");
            $(this).addClass("stop");
            $(this).val("STOP");
        }else  if($(this).hasClass("stop")){
            $(this).removeClass("stop");
            $(this).addClass("resume");
            $(this).val("RESUME");
        }
    });
})
```

for reference http://jsfiddle.net/zGMWR/1/

hope it helps

P.S. please put specific selector in jquery for your button.

Comment: @PSK Your code works fine and does it's job perfectly, you might want to consider though writing more efficiently and break down you logic to what is relevant. Size matters ;o)

Answer (score 2):

Your initial value 'start' is irrelevant here as it only appears the very first time. So a simpler solution would be:

```
$(':button').on('click', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('start stop resume');
    if (this.value !== 'STOP') {
        this.value = 'STOP';
        $(this).addClass('stop');
    } else {
        this.value = 'RESUME';
        $(this).addClass('resume');   
    }
});
```

An even shorter version would be:

```
$(':button').on('click', function(){
    this.value = this.value !== 'STOP' ? 'STOP' : 'RESUME';
    $(this).removeClass('start stop resume')
           .addClass(this.value.toLowerCase());
});
```

Side info: answer from PSK: 376 Bytes; first answer here: 223 Bytes; second answer: 174 Bytes

Of Course you can wrap it in a `$(document).ready(function(){` function if necessary

See http://jsfiddle.net/zGMWR/2/ and http://jsfiddle.net/zGMWR/3/ how it works

For a more specific selector and using event delegation you could use:

```
$('form').on('click', ':button', function(){...
```

or give the button an even more specific class name such as `play-button`